# Optimizing a Sort Method

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a program that needs to sort matches into the following order (the following is a short example):

```
PIT  
PREDICTIONS  
Match 1  
Match 2  
Quarters 1 Match 1  
Quarters 1 Match 2  
Quarters 2 Match 1  
Semis 1  
Semis 2  
Finals 1  
Finals 2
```

Note: There can be unlimited Matches, Quarters 1 - 4 only (with unlimited submatches), unlimited semis, and unlimited finals.

I've got the following method that assign a score to one of the above titles:

```
public static long getMatchScore(String name) {
    long score = 0;
    String matchName = name.toLowerCase();
    String[] tokens = matchName.split("\\s+");

    if(matchName.startsWith("pit")) score -= 100000;
    else if(matchName.startsWith("predictions")) score -= 1000;
    else if(matchName.startsWith("quals")) score = Integer.parseInt(matchName.split("\\s+")[1]);
    else if(matchName.startsWith("quarters")) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) == 1) score += 1000;
        else if(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) == 2) score += 10000;
        else if(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) == 3) score += 100000;
        else if(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) == 4) score += 1000000;

        score += Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
    }
    else if(matchName.startsWith("semis")) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) == 1) score += 10000000;
        else if(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) == 2) score += 100000000;

        score += Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
    }
    else if(matchName.startsWith("finals")) {
        score += 1000000000; 
        score += Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    }
    return score;
}
```

Then the Java method `compareTo()` is used to sort it. Is there a better way to do this rather than assigning massive numbers like `100000000`.

Comment: put all rules in an `enum` i guest

Comment: Please show us how you call this.

Comment: You can assign small numbers like 0,1,2,3,4,5, ... but it won't make any difference. The actual sorting is what will take the time if there is a large number of items, and if there isn't a large number of items it is pointless to contemplate trying to improve this code at all, as it will all execute in about a nanosecond.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have a custom `Comparable` class that contains 2 variables, title and sorting score. Each sorting score is calculated with getMatchScore()  and assigned to the sorting score variable. Then I call Collections.sort()

Comment: @Jerry06 could you provide an example of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one calls for embedding the logic in your code into a Comparable class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MatchDescription implements Comparable<MatchDescription> {

    private MatchType matchType;
    private int matchOrder = 0;
    private int subMatchOrder = 0;

    public MatchDescription(String name) {
        String matchName = name.toLowerCase().trim();
        String[] tokens = matchName.split("\\s+");

        matchType = MatchType.getByName(tokens[0]);

        if (matchType.hasMatchOrder()) {
            matchOrder = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        }
        if (matchType.hasSubmatches()) {
            subMatchOrder = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
        }
    }
```

Now, methods compareTo(T) and equals(Object) are overridden using the logic of the matches order, sub-order etc.

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MatchDescription other) {
        if (this.matchType == other.matchType)
            if (this.matchOrder == other.matchOrder)
                return (this.subMatchOrder - other.subMatchOrder);
            else
                return (this.matchOrder - other.matchOrder);
        else
            return (this.matchType.getMatchTypeOrder() - other.matchType.getMatchTypeOrder());  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return (other instanceof MatchDescription) &&
                (((MatchDescription) other).matchType == this.matchType) &&
                (((MatchDescription) other).matchOrder == this.matchOrder);
    }
```

The match types are managed via an inner enum:

```
    private enum MatchType {
        PIT("PIT",                 1, false, false),
        PREDICTIONS("PREDICTIONS", 2, false, false),
        MATCH("Match",             3, true,  false),
        QUARTERS("Quarters",       4, true,  true),
        SEMIS("Semis",             5, true,  true),
        FINALS("Finals",           6, true,  false)
        ;

        private String name;
        private int matchTypeOrder;
        private boolean hasMatchOrder;
        private boolean hasSubmatches;

        MatchType(String name, int matchTypeOrder, boolean hasMatchOrder, boolean hasSubmatches) {
            this.name           = name;
            this.matchTypeOrder = matchTypeOrder;
            this.hasMatchOrder  = hasMatchOrder;
            this.hasSubmatches  = hasSubmatches;
        }

        public boolean hasMatchOrder() {
            return hasMatchOrder;
        }

        public boolean hasSubmatches() {
            return hasSubmatches;
        }

        public static MatchType getByName(String matchName) {
            for (MatchType value : values()) {
                if (value.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(matchName))
                    return value;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private String getName() {          
            return name;
        }

        public int getMatchTypeOrder() {            
            return matchTypeOrder;
        }
    }
```

Finally, toString() presents the object nicely:

```
public String toString() {
        String description = matchType.getName();
        if (matchType.hasMatchOrder()) {
            description +=  " " + matchOrder;

            if (matchType.hasSubmatches()) 
                description +=  " Match " + subMatchOrder;
        }

        return description;
    }
```

This is an example on how to use the comparable object (notice that white spaces are also handled):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputs = new String[] {
                "PIT  ",
                "       Finals 1  ",
                "PREDICTIONS  ",
            "   Match 2  ",
            "   Quarters 1 Match 1  ",
            "   Quarters 1 Match 2  ",          
            "   Match 1  ",
        "       Semis 1  Match 1 ",
        "       Semis 2   Match 1",
        "       Finals 2",
        "   Quarters 2 Match 1  "};

        List<MatchDescription> c = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String input : inputs) {
            c.add(new MatchDescription(input));
        }
        Collections.sort(c);

        for (MatchDescription e : c) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really, really good answer. Marked as right answered and upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, and I don't say this sarcastically, if you're going to write code like `getMatchScore`, you should be spending more time learning how to write clean code, than actually whipping out more code. The [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of that method is thorugh the roof.

That said, if we recognize that your input has groups that have inherent weightage, like `Match` < `Quarters`, we should capture that in code using an `Enum`. A simple one with integer weightage should suffice, don't need a complicated one as shown by "Java Guy next door". How about the following code that I've tested to be working?

```
private static final Comparator<String> BY_GROUP = (s1, s2) -> {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e1 = toTuple(s1);
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e2 = toTuple(s2);

    Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> c = Comparator.<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>, Integer>comparing(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getValue);

    return c.compare(e1, e2);
};

private static Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> toTuple(String s) {
    String[] tokens = s.toUpperCase().split("\\s");
    Group group = Group.valueOf(tokens[0]);
    int num = tokens.length > 1 ? Integer.valueOf(tokens[1]) : Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(group.weightage(), num);
}

private enum Group {
    PIT(0), PREDICTIONS(1), MATCH(2), QUARTERS(3), SEMIS(4), FINALS(5);

    private int weightage;

    Group(int weightage) {
        this.weightage = weightage;
    }

    public int weightage() {
        return this.weightage;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> input = Arrays.asList("PIT", "PREDICTIONS", "Match 1", "Match 2",
            "Quarters 1 Match 1", "Quarters 1 Match 2", "Quarters 2 Match 1", "Semis 1", "Semis 2",
            "Finals 1", "Finals 2");

    input.sort(BY_GROUP);
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely give that a try. I did recognize that this method was sh** but I didn't quite know how to fix it. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

The first thing: the given code does contain duplicated code. Which is a bad thing by itself. But also a small performance hit.

Example: you are calling parseInt(token[0]) like 5 times or more. You could restructure the whole method to make it A) easier to read and B) compute that expression only once for example.